# Creating two separate funds in a single smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I am attempting to create a smart contract with two separate funds/ vaults. So far, I have approached it by creating two separate payable functions, arrays, and mappings with separate permissions for funding and withdrawal. Maybe there is another way for me to approach this, possible using variables, I'm not sure. Any suggestions? I am a beginner trying to learn Solidity, so any suggestions or tips would be appreciated. Also, I am trying to create it so that there are two funds. One fund, anyone is able to send ether, and only the owner is able to withdraw. Another fund, anyone is able to send ether, only the sender can withdraw the exact amount they sent, and the contract creator cannot withdraw.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL-3.0 
pragma solidity 0.8.8;

contract Variables {

    uint256 public minimum = 1e18; 
    event AccountFunded(uint256 minimum);
    address[] public investors;
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToInvestment;
    address owner;
    address[] public funders;
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToFunding;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender; 
    }

    function isOwner() private view returns (bool) {
        return msg.sender == owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier notOwner() {
        require(msg.sender != owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier checkSender () {
        assert(msg.sender == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function fundMoneyBasket () public payable notOwner checkSender {
        funders.push(msg.sender);
        addressToFunding[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    }

    function withdrawMoneybasket () public payable notOwner {
        uint256 withdrawAmount = msg.value;
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: withdrawAmount}("");
        require(success, "return transaction failed");
    }

    function fundContract () public payable {
        require(msg.value >= minimum, "NOT ENOUGH ETH, SEND MORE");
        emit AccountFunded(minimum); 
        investors.push(msg.sender);
        addressToInvestment[msg.sender] = msg.value;
        
    }

    function withdraw () public onlyOwner {
        //require(msg.sender == owner, "Not owner!");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
        for(uint256 funderIndex = 0; funderIndex < investors.length; funderIndex++ ){
        address funder = investors[funderIndex];
        addressToInvestment[funder] = 0;
        }       
        investors = new address[](0);
        (bool callSuccess, /*bytes memory dataReturned*/) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: address(this).balance}(""); /*returns 2 variables, we only care about one*/
        require(callSuccess, "Call f4iled"); 
    }


}
```

Comment: using separate functions is good way to solve this as you have done.

Comment: Thank-you very much. I'm trying to think like a programmer, as I know everything won't have a simple solution. Your reply is much appreciated.

Comment: This contract can be simplified using if-else statements. And why is your withdrawalMoneyBasket function payable?
and you are not checking and updating the mapping after withdrawl

Comment: (1st Question)I was experimenting with different functions and arguments, and stopped abruptly to come and post this question here. I knew that making it payable wouldn't work, but I was piecing together different tutorials for different solutions and just didn't get rid of it before I stopped.(2nd Question) I tried to do that using a tutorial. I implemented it the wrong way so I deleted it. It would have basically been similar to the withdraw function. How would you use the if-else statement?